# Hosting .NET 4.0 REST WCF service on IIS 5.1 (Windows XP) issue 404 (The resource cannot be found)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, web-config, iis-5

I've got a WCF-based RESTful API (.NET Framework 4.0) which works fine when hosting on IIS 7.0 (Win7) or IIS 6.0 (Server 2003). However, I found a problem hosting the website on IIS 5.1 (Windows XP) which is surprising because I thought 5.1 and 6.0 differ only by the number of hosted websites.

Everything is fine with the following request ([the result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIuFC.jpg)):

> `http://localhost/test/api/OrderService.svc`

So I guess I don't have to register any module for handling SVC files or whatsoever.
However, the following request ([the result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEFtZ.jpg)):

> `http://localhost/test/api/OrderService.svc/rest/orders?format=json`

returns HTTP code 404.
I've checked the event viewer but found nothing.

Again, everything works on IIS 7.0 and IIS 6.0.
Here is the web.config file (some things cut):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <globalization uiCulture="auto" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--Это приложение определяет конфигурацию в разделе system.web/httpHandlers.
    Если есть уверенность, что можно игнорировать эту ошибку, сообщение о ней можно отключить, установив для параметра system.webServer/validation@validateIntegratedModeConfiguration значение false.
    Для запуска приложений ASP.NET на сервере IIS 7.0 и более поздних версий предпочтительным является интегрированный режим.-->
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="AddAsmx" verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="AppService" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="soapBinding" closeTimeout="00:02:00" hostNameComparisonMode="Exact" maxBufferSize="120000" maxReceivedMessageSize="120000" >
         <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="restBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <!--http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/845d0bbd-52b4-420f-bf06-793d53ef93ba-->
        <!--<binding name="poxBinding">
        </binding>-->
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="XDDF" maxBufferSize="120000" maxReceivedMessageSize="120000" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="slBehavior" name="WcfServiceLibrary.OrderService">
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="soapBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IOrderService" />
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="restBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IOrderService" />
        <!--<endpoint address="pox" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="poxBinding" behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" contract="WcfServiceLibrary.IOrderService"/>-->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="mexHttpbinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <!--<enableWebScript/>-->
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
        <!--<behavior name="poxBehavior">
            <webHttp />
          </behavior>-->
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="slBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="returnFaults" />
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Please help. I couldn't find anything that would help.

Answer (score 3):

Doing the following worked for me.

- Select Properties of your application on IIS.
- Choose Configuration in Virtual Directory tab.
- Click Add. Select Executable as    aspnet_isapi.dll. (Normally path
  to this would be similar to
  c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll).
- Extension as **.***
- Uncheck "Check that file exists".
- Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this so that i can help others, since i had the same issue and most of the posts on WCF REST on IIS 5 are old.

There could be a problem with permissions on your App pool for that website / virtual directory , you can try to set that right and try it out.

You can refer this article for more help on this.

http://technicalwizardry.blogspot.in/2013/04/wcf-rest-service-hosted-on-iis-5.html#!/2013/04/wcf-rest-service-hosted-on-iis-5.html